# How do I make very thin border lines in CSS ? (Instagram Login Page)

Tags: css, border

i have been trying to re-create Instagram Login Page.

When you get down to the portion with "-OR-", i cannot recreate my lines to be thin.

Making it 1px still seems too fat.

I tried changing the opacity to .1, but it still looks thicker than those on Instagram page, just less visible.

I also noticed the border around that login page is way thinner than 1px but opacity looks like its 1.

I would appreciate any tips. I also want to add that i looked through as many questions about this as i could find on stackover flow but everyone seems to be saying you cannot go less than 1px and the rest is to use opacity.  Maybe its my eyes, but that line thinner and more pronounced than 1px.

Thank you

Comment: HI! try to use outline instead of border

Comment: It's a border, it's just a 1px border with a very light grey color against a white background so it may be perceived as being thinner than 1px but it's definitely 1px. If you're ever curious to know what a page is using style-wise, you can use your browser inspector to check it. `border: 1px solid rgba(219, 219, 219);`

Comment: Thank you, maybe i am just tired and need a break. I didn't even think to inspect it while i was doing it earlier for other specs. Also outline property seem to make it thinner.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp#:~:text=Note%3A%20Outline%20differs%20from%20borders,the%20width%20of%20the%20outline No, they're still the same width they just serve different purposes. https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/92wxs6q8/

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very informative. I did not know about the outline property yet, setting outline to none helped.

Comment: @Axnyc Ah yes, sorry that completely slipped my mind. Elements such as `<select>` and `<input>` have default styles, and `outline` seems to be a common one so you'll want to override those.  https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/hf4qe1ku/